# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for MyMapper in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, mapstruct, vscode-debugger

Class not found exception in Visual studio code because vs-code debug takes output class files form bin directory like eclipse but i am using GRADLE for build so MapperImpl.java which is implementation files in mapper are created in the build folder i don't know how to solve the issue i tried to change the classpath all the solutions i tried but nothing working please i need your help

I am also posting the vs code file launch.json

```
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)-Application<RestApi>",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "ae.org.nge.Application",
        "projectName": "RestApi",
        "vmArgs": "-DngeConfig=C:/Users/Manoj.Dhayalan/source/myapp/Application/config/myapp-config.properties -Dserver.port=8081 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev"

    }
```

Comment: Are you using an extension to do the debugging? It seems that the [Java Debug Extension for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/09/28/java-debug) supports Gradle.

Comment: @EricWang i am able to debug that is not the issue my mapper files that are automatically generated is throwing the run time exception

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Visual Studio Code but I managed to change the location of generated class file by putting this lines into my `build.gradle` file:

```
compileJava {
    options.setAnnotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory(file("$projectDir/src/main/generated"))
}
```

This way gradle will generate `MyMapperImpl` in `src` instead of `build` folder and it should be also recognized by VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tried it but it is still not working i am getting the same exception

Comment: Does it change the path where `MyMapperImpl` is generated?

Comment: class files are still generating inside build folder but java files are generated in the location you have mentioned scr/main/generated if i manually copy the class files generated inside build folder to bin folder it is working but i cant keep on doing that thanks for your help

Comment: Hmm, I see. MapStruct works as an annotation processor. It runs during gradle build. It generates a `.java` file and then this file is compiled as a regular source file. In your case, it seems that VS Code did not runs the annotation processor. In Intellij Idea I have to manually turn on annotation processing for project. Maybe this is also the case for VS Code.

However, if you run gradle build and `MyMapperImpl.java` is generated inside the src file and then when you build the project, VS Code should compile this file as other source files.